# Is $Ord$ weakly compact?

Tags: ordinals, infinitary-combinatorics

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ord}{Ord}$Let $c: \Ord^{[2]} \rightarrow 2$ be a $2$-coloring of the class of pairs of ordinals.

Is there a definable class-sized subclass $H$ of $\Ord$ which is $c$-homogeneous, that is, such that $c(H^{[2]}) = \{0\}$ or $c(H^{[2]}) = \{1\}$?

Comment: Define "class" in this context?

Comment: I assume the coloring is also definable, right?

Comment: Not necessarly. But I'm also interested in the case when $c$ is definable.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you can arrange a coloring which diagonalizes over all the definable classes to get a counterexample in that case. But I'm not sure, maybe I'm talking out of my fanny.

Comment: Ok, I have zero intuition about this so I'll try to think in this direction though I don't really see how to diagonalize here.

Comment: Oh, I am also somewhat clueless here. But if you work over a countable model, there are only countably many definable classes and continuum many undefinable classes. So I'm fairly sure that you can find a way to diagonalize and avoid all the definable ones.

Comment: Oh okay good idea.

Comment: And the situation is even worse is your model is non-standard. You can probably use the fact there are decreasing sequences of ordinals to define something like that, and no definable class could be homogeneous because that would give you an internal witness of ill-foundedness.

Comment: [A paper by Enayat and Hamkins](http://jdh.hamkins.org/ord-is-not-definably-weakly-compact/) would be relevant.